# Angular4 (change) event not working with jQuery select2?

Tags: angular, typescript, jquery-select2

I am using jQuery select2 in Angular 4 project, Whenever I am trying to change select2 value the respected function is not invoking

**HTML**

```
<label> Parent SKU</label>

<select id="parent_sku" formControlName="parent_sku" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.parent_sku.errors, 'disabled' : isDesginer }" (change)="selectParentSku()">
  <option *ngFor="let product of allProductsList | orderBy: 'modified_at': false " value="{{product.sku}}">{{product.sku}} : {{product.product_name}}
</option>
</select>
```

**Typescript**

```
selectParentSku() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty using the angular wrapper for Angular [ng-select2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2) so you don't have to worry about jquery.